# Make local Apache2 installation with multiple virtual hosts accessible within network

Tags: linux, networking, debian, apache-http-server

I have a local apache2 and mariaDB server running on my development machine (Debian 10). I am using virtual hosts so I can have multiple websites available at the same time. I go through the following steps to achieve my goal:

1) Create and edit the conf file for the website. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/website.conf`

2) Fill the file with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my_name@gmail.nl
    ServerName website.local
    ServerAlias www.website.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website/public_html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

3) `sudo a2ensite website.conf`

4) `sudo systemctl reload apache2`

5) Edit hosts file. `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, adding the line: `127.0.0.1 website.local`

At this point it works. When I go to `http://website.local` I will be redirected to the newly made local website.

At the moment when some other computer goes to my pc's IP address (Let's say it is : `10.0.0.100` They will go to my `/var/www/html/index.html` file. I have no idea why this works, as I have never set it up. But it does.

My wish: Going to `10.0.0.100` on a pc within my network opens a page where I can (manually) place a list that redirects to the local websites I have. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://website1.10.0.0.100/">Website1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://website2.10.0.0.100/">Website2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://website3.10.0.0.100/">Website3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to get pointed in the right direction, as I do not see how to achieve this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do could be achieved by registering the corresponding names (aka `website.local`) to your network DNS.

A name like `website1.10.0.0.100` is just impossible to implement by your own because, since it begins with a string (`website1`) it will be considered by any client as a FQDN. 
So any client will try to find out what DNS server is authoritative on `.100` Top Level Domain .... and as you probably guessed, this TLD doesn't exist.

The easiest way you can implement 3 differents sites on your machine without modifying DNS is to:

- Have 3 differents IPs addresses on your computer (using `ifconfig eth0 add 10.0.0.101`, `ifconfig eth0 add 10.0.0.102`, etc...)
- Implement IP-based virtual hosts on your Apache.
- Have a frontpage that look that way:

```
<ul>
         <li><a href="http://10.0.0.100/">Website1</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://10.0.0.101/">Website2</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://10.0.0.102/">Website3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another (more complicated) way to implement this would be to:

1. Implement your own DNS server on your machine to be authoritative on, for example, the `.bibicomputer` TLD.
2. On your `bibicomputer` DNS zone, makes `website1.bibicomputer`, `website2.bibicomputer`, etc... points to your IP address.
3. Ask your workmates to add your IP address in their DNS list (under linux: `/etc/resolv.conf`).

But i bet that IT guys on your company won't like this solution.